# Using Math.Random and vars, in JS function

Tags: javascript

how are you? 
I need help in JS code. I need to put random words within that function. Choose one of them.

This is the code:

```
// Plugin invoke
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#popup-1").slickModals({ 
(...)
 windowLocation: "center";
(...)
```

How do I do this using a math.random words in "WindowLocation"?

The words are:  "Center" or "TopRight" or "TopLeft".

something similar result:

```
// Plugin invoke
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#popup-1").slickModals({ 
(...)
 windowLocation: "center","Topright","Topleft";
(...)
```

Thank You, sorry my english bad.

Comment: Is there a list of words to choose from? `Math.random()` returns a random number between 0 and 1, and then you could multiply that by the length of the array of words to pick a random word out of it. But you need some base list, and javascript does not come with one. (example: `["Center","TopRight","TopLeft"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3]` will return one of those three words randomly)

Comment: The `;` in that line can’t be correct. If that’s an object property, you need to sparate it with `,`.

Comment: Yes, i have a list of words. my problem is put the random within this function. Example:
windowLocation: ["Center","TopRight","TopLeft"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. Math.random() gives you a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). You want to scale it up and then get the integer.

```
function randomValue() {
    var words = ["center","Topright","Topleft"];
    var length = words.length;
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*length);
    return words[i];
}
alert(randomValue());
```

Comment: Thank You :D
How do I put this function within the "window Location?"

Comment: `windowLocation: randomValue()`

Comment: You are the best!!! Thank you :DDDD

Answer (score 0):

You have to define an array with your *words*:

```
var positions = ["center","Topright","Topleft"];
```

Than you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#popup-1").slickModals({
      (...)
      windowLocation: positions[Math.floor(Math.random()*(positions.length-1))],
      (...)
   });
 });
```

You should use it so:

```
Math.random()*(positions.length)
```

This give you a range of random number that are fitted with the array size.

But are still float values, so you have to convert to integers to have a valid index:

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*(positions.length))
```

Now you have a range from 0 to position.length.

Comment: Uhm, actually you will see that `Math.floor(Math.random()*(positions.length-1))` _never returns the last item_. Thats because random is always between 0 and 1 and therefor will never be flatly 1, so what you want is `Math.floor(Math.random()*positions.length)` - since your flooring will round any number very close to 1 down to `positions.length - 1`;

Comment: Thank you for explanation :D

Comment: @somethinghere thanks I update my post. :)

Comment: Btw, you'd be right if you used `Math.round`. And corrected my accidental woopsie of my previous comment -_-.